# Windows 10 upgrade offer: Once installed is it tied to the one machine?

Tags: license, license-key, windows-10-upgrade

As many people, I have the icon in the task bar offering me to register for the upgrade to Windows 10. However, I plan to build a new machine later this year and I'm concerned that if I upgrade to Windows 10 when it's release, is my free year going to be tied to my current motherboard/CPU (or however the machine is identified)?

Comment: You will need a licence for the new machine: if you remove Windows from your current machine, **and it isn't an OEM licence**, then you should be able to transfer the licence to the new machine, whether it's Windows 7, 8 or 10. The mechanics of installing may mean that you will need to install the earlier Windows first and upgrade again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm concerned that if I upgrade to Windows 10 when it's release, is my
>   free year going to be tied to my current motherboard/CPU (or however
>   the machine is identified)?

This entirely depends on what type of license you have.  OEM machines that came with Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 are tied to that machine.  Once you upgrade to Windows 10, that installation also, is tied to the machine.  Microsoft considers the "machine" to be the motherboard.

If you have Retail license of either Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 this provides you the right to transfer the license, a reasonable amount of times ( i.e. not unlimited ) to other machines, rights remain unmodified and continue through to  Windows 10 per the Windows 10 EULA.

> 4. Transfer. The provisions of this section do not apply if you acquired the software as a consumer in Germany or in any of the countries listed on
>      this site (aka.ms/transfer), in which case any transfer of the
>      software to a third party, and the right to use it, must comply with
>      applicable law.
>
>    - Software preinstalled on device. If you acquired the software
>        preinstalled on a device (and also if you upgraded from software
>        preinstalled on a device), you may transfer the license to use the
>        software directly to another user, only with the licensed device. The
>        transfer must include the software and, if provided with the device,
>        an authentic Windows label including the product key. Before any
>        permitted transfer, the other party must agree that this agreement
>        applies to the transfer and use of the software.
>    - Stand-alone software. If you acquired the software as
>        stand-alone software (and also if you upgraded from software you
>        acquired as stand-alone software), you may transfer the software to
>        another device that belongs to you. You may also transfer the software
>        to a device owned by someone else if (i) you are the first licensed
>        user of the software and (ii) the new user agrees to the terms of this
>        agreement. You may use the backup copy we allow you to make or the
>        media that the software came on to transfer the software. Every time
>        you transfer the software to a new device, you must remove the
>        software from the prior device. You may not transfer the software to
>        share licenses between devices.

[Windows 10 EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm)

Comment: Absolutely, this Is spelled out in very easy to read language in the Windows 10 EULA.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - This was asked before Windows 10 build 10240 was released which presented the Windows 10 EULA on the initial boot.

Comment: Yes, but you answered it 48 minutes ago ;)  I was just agreeing with you and providing additional information.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Yes;  I understand.