# If I've overwritten my main Windows installation, can I get my license key back?

Tags: windows, license

I am currently working on a machine that had Windows 7 installed by default. Many years later, this instillation was upgraded to Windows 10 via the free official online upgrade program that happened shortly after Window 10's release. One day, the whole thing broke terribly and I was forced to remove Windows and change operating systems. Is it possible to retrieve my old license key? The following may be of relevance:

- No significant changes have been made to the machine's hardware, meaning that whatever Microsoft uses to check against license reuse will still be valid.
- The original Windows 7 recovery environment should still be on the machine, although I fear attempting to boot in to it.
- I have a backup (via copy and paste) of every file that was on the machine's main drive before I installed a new operating system. This includes files like the C:\Windows folder.
- I probably have the box that the machine came in somewhere. It also has all of its original labels.

Comment: I've done this myself more than once and actually had to call Microsoft.

Comment: If you did the Windows 10 free upgrade on that machine then as long as it was actually activated (I.e. you used it) then all you should need to do is download the Windows 10 install media and when it asks you for a key then click "skip". It should connect to the internet and activate itself.

Comment: @Mokubai That's too good to be true. Can you provide a source for that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/947232/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-on-new-hard-disk

Comment: @J.Mini Also look at this [old Windows 10 article](https://pureinfotech.com/how-activation-works-windows-10-digital-entitlement-vs-product-key/) and this [official Microsoft activation documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activate) regarding Digital Licenses (Entitlements/Upgrades) if you would like separate confirmation.

Comment: @Anaksunaman That second link is suggesting that having a linked Microsoft account is important.

Comment: When Windows is installed by a large OEM (e.g., HP, Dell, et al.), the activation key goes into firmware, so even with a complete drive replacement, it's still accessible.

Comment: @K7AAY How can a user recover this?

Comment: If the key is in your firmware, reinstalling Windows will access it automatically. However, I know of no tool which can retrieve it short of reinstalling Windows.