# Using OEM key when reinstalling windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, oem

I have a Dell XPS 13 that originally had Windows, but I removed it because I wanted to use Ubuntu. Unfortunately after some time I started having issues with the Wifi (which are a common problem with this laptop) and have decided to resintall windows.

Can I use the OEM key for activating it?

At some point the official Dell support changed a part of my pc because it was making a lot of noise and I was giving a paper with the new OEM key used to activate it.

Comment: You don't need to enter a product key in order to install Windows 10 on a Dell device[.]  Windows 10 can be reinstalled, and it will automatically activate, when prompted to enter a product key you can proceed to the next step[.](https://superuser.com/questions/947232/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-on-new-hard-disk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Windows 10 was originally installed (it was according to the above), then then license is in the Microsoft Licensing Server.  You can install Windows 10 from the Dell Recovery USB (preferable) or the Windows 10 Installation USB. Once installed it will activate itself from the above server

Comment: this has been answered here a thousand times, it is better to close vote as dupe rather than answer it again.