# Install Windows on a new SSD with the same product key,

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have just bought a new SSD replace my old, smaller one and would like to install Windows 10 on it. I guess I could `dd` the Windows partition onto the new drive, but I'm planning to start a new Windows install.

Will it work if I just unplug the old drive, put in the new one and install Windows off a bootable USB stick then enter the product key I used to activate my old install? If no, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall Windows 10 on new hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/947232/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-on-new-hard-disk). There are other applicable duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

> Will it work if I just unplug the old drive, put in the new one and
> install Windows off a bootable USB stick

Yes.  You can change a drive and not lose your licensing. Windows 10 and 11.

Do you need to enter your product key?  Likely not. I have not had to do that. Licensing is maintained in the Microsoft Licensing Server.

Of course, make sure everything on the old SSD is thoroughly backed up.

What you are trying to do works fine. I have done it several times and no issues.

When you install (totally fresh) it will ask you to set up the machine as if it were new out of the box and you can change the account at that time if you wish.

Comment: Is it necessary to have a Microsoft account for the Windows account for everything to go smoothly?

Comment: You do not need the same account and you do not have to have a Microsoft account. It will work in any event. It will ask you for your account and you can change at that point.

Comment: If only the SSD has changed, then this will indeed work. Otherwise, you can get this to work by first logging into a microsoft account with this key active, and then on first boot on the new install, login with that same account to activate windows with that key.