# I installed a program that freezes my pc

Tags: microsoft

The problem I have with my PC is the following:

A few weeks ago I installed a program called "TRON" that is used to optimize computers,

I installed it step by step thanks to a YouTube video and I saw in comments that it worked for many people, but not to me.

It happens that after using the program, the next day I turned on my pc and the screen stayed black for about 10 minutes and then returned to normal.

The thing is that then I wanted to look for something from the Windows search engine that is in the left corner and I was surprised that it did not allow me to write (note that I can write in Google Chrome and other pages within the browser).

It also won't let me open common programs like:

- Word
- PowerPoint
- Excel
- Paint,
- etc.

On top of that, it doesn't let me delete folders that are as "device administrator".

I tried to delete all traces of "TRON" but as I said before, I can't delete anything.

I also tried to reset my PC from configuration and when I press the "reset" button the screen remains frozen for several minutes, the same thing happens when I do this in properties and security of some folders, it freezes and after a few minutes it closes and gives up.

Normally when I do that, when it closes it leaves me with this message "This file does not have any associated applications". I can't get into task manager ANY way possible either.

That is my problem, what if I can do is simply enter Google and surf the internet.

Please, if someone knows what is happening to my PC, I ask you to help me and explain it to me.

Comment: Lo siento mi amigo. Este sitio debe estar en inglés. Las reglas del sitio dicen esto. Su pregunta probablemente será cerrada. Prueba con el traductor de google. Será lo suficientemente bueno. -- ***loose translation*** -- I am sorry my friend. This site must be in English.  The site rules say this. Your question will probably be closed.  Try google translate.  It will be good enough.

Comment: Te arreglé esto. Use inglés en el futuro para este sitio, por favor. -- ***translation*** -- I fixed this for you.  Use English in the future for this site please.

Comment: it is possible that you installed malware ... if it is not malware, then maybe you have to configure the program

Comment: I have bad news. The program you installed was malware. The video that suggested it should be reported.

Comment: If all else fails, reinstalling from a USB or optical disk might be the only option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall Windows 10 on new hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/947232/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-on-new-hard-disk)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter into Windows safe mode, maybe through that it is possible to remove the software that you have installed. To enter into safe mode when you are in the login screen read [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234).